# Am having a matrix multiplication issue with CVXPY

Tags: python, cvxpy

Updated code ...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cvxpy import *
cvxpy.multiply
import yfinance as yf
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

assets = ['TSLA', 'MSFT', 'FB', 'AAPL', 'VZ']

yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(assets)

data = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data(start_date='2019-01-01', 
                                                  end_date='2019-12-31', 
                                                  time_interval='weekly')

prices_df = pd.DataFrame({
    a: {x['formatted_date']: x['adjclose'] for x in data[a]['prices']} for a in assets})

prices_df


# get symbol names
symbols = prices_df.columns


returns = prices_df.pct_change().T
returns = returns.fillna(0)
returns

r = np.asarray(np.mean(returns, axis=1))
r = np.nan_to_num(r)

C = np.asmatrix(np.cov(returns))
C = np.nan_to_num(C)


for j in range(len(symbols)):
    print('%s: Exp Ret = %f, Risk = %f' %(symbols[j], r[j], C[j,j]*0.5))

################################################################################

# Number of variables
n = len(symbols)

# The variables vector
x = Variable(n)

# The minimum return
req_return = 0.02

# The return
ret = r.T@X

# The risk in xT.Q.x format
risk = quad_form(x, C)

# The core problem definition with the Problem class from CVXPY
prob = Problem(Minimize(risk), [sum(x)==1, ret >= req_return, x >= 0])


try:
    prob.solve()
    print ("Optimal portfolio")
    print ("----------------------")
    for s in range(len(symbols)):
       print (" Investment in {} : {}% of the portfolio".format(symbols[s],round(100*x.value[s],2)))
    print ("----------------------")
    print ("Exp ret = {}%".format(round(100*ret.value,2)))
    print ("Expected risk    = {}%".format(round(100*risk.value**0.5,2)))
except:
    print ("Error")
```

When I hit this line:

```
ret = r.T@X
```

I get this error.

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 128 is different from 5)
```

The original source code is from here.

https://tirthajyoti.github.io/Notebooks/Portfolio_optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning, not an error. So your code should be able to run anyway. The question is, does it do what you expect it to do?

As the warning suggests, the `*` multiplication operator might be ambiguous. The line that caused it is:

`ret = r.T*x`

here you want to multiply two vectors. The correct way is to think about them as matrix, therefore is using `@` operator:

`ret = r.T@x`

Which is the correct way to use dot product. Further explanations can be found in the [documentation](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/functions/index.html).

Comment: If I do this: ret = cvxpy.multiply(r,x)
I get ret = Expression(AFFINE, UNKNOWN, (5,))
Then, when I get to the try...except, I get all errors.
It's the same thing if I use: ret = r.T@x
Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, the element-wise is my mistake. You actually want only the `@` operator. Are you sure it's not working? cause `r.T@X` is working for me (I took just `r=np.array([3,3,3])` for example)

Comment: I just updated my original post will ALL my source code. I made a few small changes in the past couple days. The expected risk and expected return works fine. The 'ret' doesn't run, so the loop for 'Investment in' doesn't run. Thoughts?

Comment: Did my updated code run for you?

Comment: Expect for switching `X` to `x`, I don't get the same error. There is an error for `prob.solve()` as it returns "inf" instead of a solution, but that is a different issue. There is no problem with the `ret=r.T@x`